# How to make Spark read only specified rows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

Suppose I'm selecting given rows from a large table `A`. The target rows are given either by a small index table `B`, or by a list `C`. The default behavior of

```
A.join(broadcast(B), 'id').collect()
```

or

```
A.where(col('id').isin(C)).collect()
```

will create a task that reads in *all* data of `A` before filtering out the target rows. Take the broadcast join as an example, in the task DAG, we see that the `Scan parquet` procedure determines columns to read, which in this case, are all columns.

[image: Task DAG]

The problem is, since each row of `A` is quite large, and the selected rows are quite few, ideally it's better to:

1. read in only the `id` column of `A`;
2. decide the rows to output with broadcast join;
3. read in only the *selected* rows to output from `A` according to step 2.

Is it possible to achieve this?

BTW, rows to output could be scattered in `A` so it's not possible to make use of partition keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will create a task that reads in all data of A

You're wrong. While the first scenario doesn't push any filters, other than `IsNotNull` on `join` key in case of inner or left join, the second approach will push `In` down to the source.

If `isin` list is large, this might not necessary be faster, but it is optimized nonetheless.

If you want to fully benefit from possible optimization you should still use bucketing (`DISTRIBUTE BY`) or partitioning (`PARTITIONING BY`). These are useful in the `IS IN` scenario, but bucketing can be also used, in the first one, where `B` is too large to be broadcasted.

Comment: I could see the pushed filter in the "Scan parquet" procedure ([IsNotNull(id), EqualTo(id, xxxxxx)]), but when I tested it on a large parquet, Spark still seems to read in all data. I wonder why...

Comment: I did more experiments, and it seems that this pushdown filter is only effective on certain data types. In my case, however, id of string type is not included.